# Identifying Date Clashes using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am looking to identify rows using linq where there is a date clash. I have (for this example) 5 columns

```
ID   ref_id   ref_Name   Borrow_Date  Return_Date
1    1343     Gate       13/09/2011   20/09/2011
2    1352     Door       20/09/2011   22/09/2011
3    1343     Gate       17/09/2011   21/09/2011
```

In this case my 'Gate' is clashing because someone wants to borrow it when someone else also wants to borrow it.

Is there anyway to identify the date range clashes using linq easily?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be like this. It might be more performant variants out there though:

```
var collisions = myList.Where( d1 => !myList.Where( d => d != d1).All( d2 =>  d1.Return_Date <= d2.Borrow_Date|| d1.Borrow_Date >= d2.Return_Date));
```

This will return all rows that overlap with at least one other row. In the case above it will return all three of them, since the line with ID 3 overlaps both 1 and 2. If you change 1 to have `Return_Date` 17/09/2011, it will return only 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of objects with properties as shown in your table, you can find out the books with the same title that have conflicting dates using something like this:

(Haven't tested this code, so there might be some typo bugs.)

```
var collisions = collection
                .Join(collection, x => x.ref_Name, y => y.ref_Name, 
                                (x, y) => new {
                                                ID_x = x.ID, 
                                                ID_y = y.ID, 
                                                ref_id = x.ref_id, 
                                                ref_Name = x.ref_Name, 
                                                Borrow_Date_x = x.Borrow_Date, 
                                                Borrow_Date_y = y.Borrow_Date, 
                                                Return_Date_x = x.Return_Date, 
                                                Return_Date_y = y.Return_Date
                                                }
                        )
                .Where( z => (z.Return_Date_x > z.Borrow_Date_y && z.Borrow_Date_x < z.Return_Date_y))
                .Where( z => z.ID_x != z.ID_y);
```

You will probably get duplicates of results. (i.e. ID 1 and 3, and ID 3 and 1)

Answer (score 0):

Although it is certainly possible to identify these clashes in the database once they have occurred, would it not be a better to prevent the second person from borrowing an item when it is already scheduled to be borrowed. In this case this would be a simple matter of testing to ensure no existing rows with a ref_id of 1343 have a return date equal to or greater then the new requested borrow date.